# AWS Cloudfront provisioning - lambda_function_association

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

Using Terraform, I am provisioning CloudFront. One of the attribute is `lambda_function_association` where we associate a lambda to the CloudFront.

I get the following error message complaining about lambda function memory size

```
  Error: error updating CloudFront Distribution (ENLY37UZ3CJCF): 
     InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation: The function memory size is larger than the maximum 
     allowed size for functions that are triggered by a CloudFront event: 1024 
     Max allowed: 128 Function: arn:aws:lambda:us-eas-1-myaccount:function:myaccount- 
    dev-cloudfrontheaders1:2  

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "clientcloudfrontdistrotest" {


  default_cache_behavior {
      forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      cookies {
          forward = "none"
      }
   }


   lambda_function_association {
      event_type   = "viewer-response"
     include_body = false
     lambda_arn =  var.lambda_arn
  
   } 
   target_origin_id       = var.targetoriginid
   viewer_protocol_policy = var.viewerprotocolpolicy
  }
 }
  resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "origin_access_identity" {
  comment = "Origin Access ID for admin UI"

}
```

Comment: And may I kindly ask - what is your question? It seems like you are facing a limitation of AWS.

Comment: How to search for this limitation in aws docs please?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda@edge has number of [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-lambda-at-edge), one of which is max 128MB ram. All limitations are here:

- [Quotas on Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-lambda-at-edge)